# "Spring Boot project why not data perform proper CURD operation in add, update and delete page/button ?"

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, thymeleaf

"my question why not data perform  proper CURD operation in add, update and delete page/button?"
"why to show in browser index or addnew ,update text, why not show html pages?"

"having looked at several similar problems here and applied the logic to my situation, I'm still stumped with a crud operation failure in my Spring/JPA app." #springbootproblem #support #help
`StudentMasterController.java`

````
    package com.rinfotek.iiserp.controller;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import com.rinfotek.iiserp.entity.StudentMaster;
    import com.rinfotek.iiserp.service.StudentMasterServiceImpl;
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/student")
    public class StudentMasterController {
    //  @Autowired
    //  StudentMasterService studentService;
        @Autowired
        private StudentMasterServiceImpl studentServiceImpl;
        //thymeleaf testing
         @PostMapping("/save")
        public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student")  StudentMaster student) {
            studentServiceImpl.save(student);
             return "redirect:/";
        }
        //thymeleaf testing
        @GetMapping("/")
        public String viewStudentMasterHomesPage(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("allstudentlist", studentServiceImpl.getAllStudents());
            return "index";
        }
        @GetMapping("/addnew")
        public String addNewStudent(Model model) {
            StudentMaster student = new StudentMaster();
            model.addAttribute("student", student);
            return "newstudent";
        }
        //update student 
        @PutMapping("/updatestudent/{id}")
        public String updateForm(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id, Model model) {
            StudentMaster student = studentServiceImpl.getById(id);
            model.addAttribute("student", student);
            return "update";
        }
        //delete student 
        @DeleteMapping("/deleteStudent/{id}")
        public String deleteThroughId(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {
            studentServiceImpl.deleteViaId(id);
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }




```StudentMasterService.java```
package com.rinfotek.iiserp.service;
import java.util.List;
import com.rinfotek.iiserp.entity.StudentMaster;
public interface StudentMasterService {
    StudentMaster addStudent(StudentMaster student);
    StudentMaster getStudentMasterById(Integer sId);
    void updateStudentMaster(StudentMaster student);
    void deleteStudentMasterById(Integer sId);
    List<StudentMaster> getAllStudents();
}
````

`StudentServiceImpl.java`

```
package com.rinfotek.iiserp.service;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.rinfotek.iiserp.entity.StudentMaster;
import com.rinfotek.iiserp.repository.StudentMasterRepository;
@Service
public  class StudentMasterServiceImpl implements StudentMasterService {
@Autowired
private StudentMasterRepository repository;
@Override
public StudentMaster addStudent(StudentMaster student) {
    return repository.save(student);
}
@Override
public StudentMaster getStudentMasterById(Integer sId) {
    return repository.findById(sId).get();
}
@Override
public List<StudentMaster> getAllStudents() {
    return repository.findAll();
}
public void save(StudentMaster student) {
    repository.save(student);
    
}
public StudentMaster getById(Integer sId)
{
    Optional<StudentMaster> optional = repository.findById(sId);
    StudentMaster student = null;
    if (optional.isPresent())
        student = optional.get();
    else
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Student not found for id : " + sId);
    return student;
}
 public void deleteViaId(Integer sId)
{
     repository.deleteById(sId);
}
}
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Student</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container my-2" align="center">
<h3>Student List</h3>
<a th:href="@{/student/addnew}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3" >Add Student</a>
    <table style="width:80%" border="1"
           class = "table table-striped table-responsive-md">
    <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Current Class</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr th:each="student:${allstudentlist}">
        <td th:text="${student.name}"></td>
        <td th:text="${student.currentClass}"></td>
        <td> <a th:href="@{/updatestudent/{id}(id=${student.id})}"
                class="btn btn-primary">Update</a>
                <a th:href="@{/deleteStudent/{id}(id=${student.id})}"
                class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`newstudent.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Student Management System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Student Management System</h1>
        <hr>
        <h2>Save Student</h2>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/student/save}" th:object="${student}"
            method="POST">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" placeholder="Student Name"
                class="form-control mb-4 col-4"> <input type="text"
                th:field="*{currentClass}" placeholder="Current Class"
                class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2">Save
                Student</button>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <a th:href="@{/student/}"> Back to Student List</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`update.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Student Management System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Student Management System</h1>
        <hr>
        <h2>Update Student</h2>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/student/save}" th:object="${student}"
            method="POST">
            <!-- Add hidden form field to handle update -->
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
            <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">              
                <input type="text" th:field="*{currentClass}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Update Student</button>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <a th:href = "@{/student/}"> Back to Student List</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I paste this url on browser: `localhost:8020/student/addnew` then show the only this text "newstudent" and
when `localhost:8020/student` then show the only this text "index" and url: `localhost:8020/student/save` then show the text

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not supported org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Comment: And what exactly is failing? Edit to add exception and stacktrace to your question, at the very least.

Comment: when i paste this url on browser: http://localhost:8020/student/addnew then show the only this text "newstudent"   and when  http://localhost:8020/student/ then show the only this text "index"  and url: http://localhost:8020/student/save then show the text "There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Controller class.

The error message pretty much says it. You're getting that error when you go to `localhost:8020/student/save` because there's no GET mapping for `/student/save`. You only have POST mapping.

Possible solution:

```
@GetMapping("/save)
public String saveStudent(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
    //return the appropriate view;
}
```